# vim: strange v:count behavior in normal-mode mapping

Tags: vim

I'm working on a normal-mode mapping, and stumbled upon some surprising behavior:

First, here is a mapping that works, and does what I want:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>_ ':<C-U>normal' . v:count . 'Ix<ESC>'
```

So I can type `3,_` (`,` is my leader character) and insert 3 `x` characters.

No problem. However, I would expect this simpler one to work, too:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>_ v:count . 'Ix<ESC>'
```

But with that, if I type `3,_`, it inserts 33 `x` characters.
If I use `4,_`, I get 44, etc.

What's going on, here?

More importantly, does anybody know a good way to debug this stuff, so I can see how that expression is getting expanded, and not have to ask on SO every time I have an issue like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First here is your fixed mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>_ Ix<ESC>
```

The `{count}` will be passed into the `I` command by default. Unless the count is being passed into a different part of your mapping you can often just leave it out.

#### Why does the following mapping work?

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>_ ':<C-U>normal' . v:count . 'Ix<ESC>'
```

The count is being passed into the `:normal` command here, but this mapping is using `<c-u>` to clear out the `{count}`/range. You can see count in action by doing `3:` vs `3:<c-u>`. So without the `<c-u>` this mapping would yield:

```
:.,+2normal 3Ix<ESC>
```

With the `<c-u>` your mapping will yeild:

```
:normal 3Ix<ESC>
```

#### Why does the following mapping not work?

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>_ v:count . 'Ix<ESC>'
```

Simply using `v:count` does not clearing the current `{count}`. You need to clear the `{count}` directly or create a mapping that takes advantage of it. As this is an expression mapping the following `3,_` will convert to `33Ix<ESC>`. Where the first `3` is given count and `3Ix<ESC>` is what the expression returned.